# java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert a video file into a byte array, like so:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case VIDEO_SELECT_CODE:


                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    try {
                        FileInputStream importdb = new FileInputStream(getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r").getFileDescriptor());
                        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        int nRead;


                        byte[] bytes = new byte[100000];

                        while ((nRead = importdb.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length)) != -1) {
                            buffer.write(bytes, 0, nRead);
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
}
```

I get the following error message :

> java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

when I try to open some `.mp4` files  while I don't get it while opening some others.

Why could this be?

(this snippet of code is the `onActivityResult` method for the Activity in which I select a video from the phone's internal storage, so `uri` is the URI for that selected video file)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the Parcel File Descriptor which is returned by `openFileDescriptor()`. Besides Input/Output streams, you must also remember about closing the Asset/Parcel File Descriptor at the end.